# Internal SSD: Create a partition in unallocated space

Tags: macos, ssd, partition

I have a MacBookPro 13" Retina late 2013 with an internal SSD, there is 1TB unallocated space, I tried Disk Utility but it doesn't let me create a new partition there (it just does nothing when I click 'Apply').  Verify shows no error, also repair.

```
gpt -r show disk0
start            size   index   contents
    0               1           PMBR
    1               1           Pri GPT header
    2              32           Pri GPT table
   34               6
   40          409600       1   GPT part - C12A7328-....
409640     1953083352
1953492992     716800       2   GPT part - DE94....
1954209792        295
1954210087         32           Sec GPT table
1954210119          1           Sec GPT header


fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0   geometry: 121643/255/63 [1954210120 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl   hd  sec   - cyl   hd sec  [    start -       size]
 1: EE 1023  254   63   - 1023 254  63  [        1 - 1954210119] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0    0    0   -    0   0   0  [        0 -          0] unused 
 3: 00    0    0    0   -    0   0   0  [        0 -          0] unused 
 4: 00    0    0    0   -    0   0   0  [        0 -          0] unused 

diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:       TYPE NAME                  SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:   GUID_partition_scheme         *1.0 TB    disk0
   1:      EFI EFI                     209.7 MB  disk0s1 
   2: DE94...                          367.0 MB  disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:       TYPE NAME                  SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:  Apple_partition_scheme         *1.3 GB    disk1
   1:  Apple_partition_map             30.7 KB   disk1s1
   2:      Apple_HFS OS X Base System   1.3 GB   disk1s2
```

I've booted with CMD-R, can I unmount the disk0? I guess not, but I'm not sure.

I've created an usb stick with OS X 10.9 but the notebook could not boot from this stick.

Is there a way to make a new perdition from the existing free space with diskutil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If solved the problem by
- Boot with ALT CMD P R
  After this the former bootcamp partition was again there.
- New partitioning of the ssd with only one partition having 1TB
- By using Web-recovery installation of Mac OS X
- Creating a new bootcamp partition with bootcamp assistent.

My concern was when remove the partition disk0s2 (with recovery OS X) a new installation of Mac OS X is not possible, I wasn't aware of the function Web-recovery.